# Pure Java reimplementation of GraphViz?

Tags: java, drawing, graphviz, graph-visualization

Is there an Open Source java alternative to GraphViz? I'm aware of the existence of Grappa which basically wraps the Graph interface to GraphViz as an JavaAPI. However the layouting is still done by the GraphViz binaries.

I'm looking for a pure-java, open source library providing the same functions and layouting algorithms as GraphViz.

Comment: 'However, current versions of the software are now licensed on an open source basis only under The Eclipse Public License (EPL). ' - http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php

Comment: Looking at the source papers is well worth it http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php

Comment: https://github.com/jamisonjiang/graph-support, This is probably the closest project to what you describe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have a look at [JUNG (Java Universal Network/Graph Framework)](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) which has visualization and analytics functions. It's open source.

Comment: been using JUNG now for a while, having tried Gephi and some others, it seems to work really well, though I've already reached the point where I'm going to have to create my own layout algorithm to get what I want.

Answer (score 18):

Interestingly, the Eclipse project has an SWT/JFace component/framework capable of displaying and generating (import/export) Graphviz's 'DOT' format, in pure Java:

[ZEST (home page & download links)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest)

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphviz_DOT_as_a_DSL_for_Zest for usage examples.

Although ZEST is touted as an Eclipse plugin, it does seem that the DOT-manipulation API's can be used standalone and external to an Eclipse installation.

To clarify, the DOT functionality is a part of the [ZEST 2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest) functionality, which itself is a sub-component of the [GEF4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4) project.

Cheers

Rich

**Update (May 2017)** https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

Comment: From the FAQ on Zest which is part of GEF for eclipse:
Can I develop a standalone GEF application without use of the Eclipse platform?
The official answer is No, this is not supported.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was not suggesting that you don't need the Eclipse framework/API, just that you can code your own, standalone, DOT-based application, independently of the ZEST Eclipse plugin.

Comment: As far as I was able to use this plugin I can tell that it does not support subgraphs nor colors or any other specialities about DOT.

Comment: The problem I have with nidi3/graphviz-java is that it's a hack built upon another hack (it bundles a V8 JS engine to run viz.js, which is Graphviz compiled to JS with emscripten). The dependency is just as large and slow as you might expect from that.

Answer (score 8):

You could look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) though I have never used it so cannot comment on now it compares to GraphViz.

Answer (score 6):

[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html) seems to provide all this, but it's not free and not really cheap either. But then again it seems to be a very professional product (haven't used it, except in [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html), which can be used for free).

Answer (score 4):

I guess [ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html) is what you want. I really like ZGRViewer and AJaPaD.

Comment: That is a really nice viewer. It required almost no effort to get it working on my Windows 7. Hopefully, I will be able to hack its source code to integrate it with my Java application.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html) about four years ago, and it was excellent. It's costly (though less than JGraph, apparently) but I work in a CS research lab and had access to their generous academic pricing.

Comment: To clarify, JGraph is BSD licensed, it costs nothing.