# How can I generate a network map graphic from a CSV file?

Tags: java, networking

If I have a simple list of network information that looks like this, how can I programmatically generate a graphic network map?   I am just looking for ideas on what Java API I could examine and try out.

```
System   | Related-To       |  Parent
System1  |   System6        |
System2  |                  |  System1
System3  |                  |  System1
System4  |   System6        |  System1
System5  |                  |  System1
System6  |                  |  System4
System7  | System2, System3 | System4
System7  |   System5        | System1
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654294/java-graphviz

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the open source JFreeChart library to help with the graphical elements.