# How to use graphviz in my java program to draw the state chart

Tags: java, mapping, graphviz, statechart

I want to use graphviz to draw the statechart in my java program to show the flow. How to use the Graphviz program in my java program to draw the state charts.

Comment: This SO question may be of use to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654294/java-graphviz